# ipython notebook error with tornado

Tags: tornado, jupyter-notebook

When I try to use cmd to open ipython notebook, I got this

error:tornado.access:500 GET/static/base/images/favicon.ico?v=4e6c6be5716444f7ac7b902e7f388939<::1> 150.00ms referer=None

I tried to reinstall the python2.7.8 , pythonxy and chrome. But it still failed.
Can anyone have any idea to help me fix that?

Answer (score 0):

i think you start the python on behalf of user, that do not have access to python source files. Try to start the python application as root.

Comment: thank you so much, but sorry,I only know how to start ipython notebook with CMD. Do you mean I need to start python first before I start ipython notebook?